# Upgrade from SQL 2008 to SQL 2012: do we need to change connection string?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql

We are seeing some terrible performance degradation having just upgraded our MVC4 application from SQL 2008 to SQL 2012.

Queries run directly in management studio on the database server run somewhat slower than they did prior to the upgrade (up to twice as slow).

Queries run from the web server (a separate machine) run hugely slower, some more than four times slower. We pointed the finger at the network between the two machines, but our hosting company have suggested that the connection string should have changed for SQL 2012. I'm not aware that SQL 2012 connection strings are any different to SQL 2008 connection strings - am I right?

Thanks!

Our connection string has been unchanged for years and looks like this: 
Server=111.111.111.111;Database=MyDbName;User ID=MyDbUser;Password=MyDbPassword;

**UPDATE: This eventually turned out to be a faulty physical port on the firewall!**

Comment: The connection string wouldn't degrade performance. Its only going to connect, or it isn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Connection strings have not changed for some time unless you use one of the new connection-based features and while there are some in between the versions you have (availability groups) they are not relevant when not used.

So, in your case - definitely nothing has changed.

You will have to run a profiler and find out why. This is something you should have done before upgrading production - standard approach.

Comment: Thanks. We did test the upgrade of course but didn't experience the same problems.

Comment: Agreed, most likely not.  @Edmond If you're connecting successfully at all then you shouldn't need to change connection strings.  There is a new SQL Native Client with SQL2012 so OLE DB connections should change their provider.  Is this a single-instance SQL server?  Can you post the connection string you're using?  Also, did you change the compatability level of any of your databases during the upgrade?

Comment: Thanks. Connection string added to question. We didn't change the compatibility level, and nor did we reindex or run any maintenance scripts after the upgrade which I'm thinking now may have been very naive.

Comment: @Edmond Yes, you'll want to do that.  At the very least run an update statistics.

Comment: Definitely regenerate statistics.... and then profile. 2012 had serious optimizer changes....

Comment: @squillman Thanks. I don't believe update statistics carries much risk (correct me if I'm wrong), but I have read that a full regression test would be required after changing the compatibility level. Any idea what general type of issues changing the compatibility level can throw up?

Comment: @Edmond Update statistics can have a huge impact.  The query optimizer was completely rewritten for 2012.  If the optimizer is using bad execution plans then that can be all of your pain right there.  Even though all the execution plans have been regenerated there might be one that's not great that's causing your problem.  After that, then it's off to a profiler trace.  Regarding compatibility levels, you'll want to review the deprecated features list before updating.  If your db or client code uses something deprecated you will need to change code prior to updating compatibility.

Comment: @squillman just in case you're curious, we ran updatestatistics last night in the staging environment. It doesn't seem to have had any effect on the speed but I'm sure it's the right thing to do so thanks for the suggestion. Hosting company seem to think we need a different processor in the machine - somehow the new one is more powerful yet less capable than the previous one. Fingers crossed on that!